# Why does array() > int evaluates to true?

Tags: php, arrays

Debugging some code I found a similar case in which there was a check if array's values are more than 2. This was always evaluating to true, because the code was something like this (not real sample)

['key' => 'value'] > 2 // this is evaluated to true.

I started digging and it turned out actually that in php the following is true:

```
php > var_dump([] > 1);
bool(true)
php > var_dump([] > 0);
bool(true)
php > var_dump([] > 10000);
bool(true)
php > var_dump(array() > 100);
bool(true)
```

Why is this evaluated to `true`?
I have some more experience in nodejs and this will have completely different behaviour but it seems more logical, for example in js the following is true `[] == 0`
and this is false `[] > 1`

Comment: The only real proper answer here would be a type error, but both PHP and Javascript are very timid about those…

Comment: Not sure, but I would assume "an array is bigger than an integer".

Comment: Yes, I saw the already answered answer and there is a link to the manual... How stupid of me to not notice it :D

```object vs anything - object is always greater```
```array vs  anything - array is always greater```

https://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types